# How to deploy a cloud function in a subfolder of my bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a cloud function to a subfolder of my bucket like this

```
gcloud beta functions deploy $FUNCTION_NAME_STAGING --stage-bucket bucket/staging --trigger-http --entry-point handle
```

but I get this error

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) argument --stage-bucket: Invalid value 'bucket/staging': Bucket must only contain lower case Latin letters, digits and characters . _ -. It must start and end with a letter or digit and be from 3 to 232 characters long. You may optionally prepend the bucket name with gs:// and append / at the end.

I cannot find a way to do it in the documentation. Is it possible ?